# Error while adding Complex numbers

Tags: c++

In below program I am getting 2 errors at below lines.

```
 r = sum(p,q); //Function sum should have a prototype.
 r = sum(p,q); //Cannot convert int to complex
```

Kindly advise the changes in the code.

Note: I have to do the code by passing objects of complex class to add and also the addition should return a complex number.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

class Complex
{
  private:
    int real;
    int imag;

  public:
    void getNo()
    {
     cout<<"Enter real part : "<<endl;
     cin>>real;
     cout<<"Enter imaginary part : "<<endl;
     cin>>imag;
    }

    void showNo()
    {
     cout<<real<<"+"<<imag<<"i";
    }

   Complex sum(Complex, Complex);
};

Complex Complex :: sum(Complex c1, Complex c2)
{
  Complex a;
  a.real = c1.real + c2.real;
  a.imag = c1.imag + c2.imag;
  return a;
}

 void main()
 {
  clrscr();
  Complex p,q,r,s;
  p.getNo();
  q.getNo();
  cout<<endl<<"First complex number is : ";
  p.showNo();

  cout<<endl<<"Second complex number is : ";
  q.showNo();

  r = sum(p,q);
  cout<<"Addtion of the complex no is : ";
  r.showNo();  

  getch();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain first error more correctly?

Comment: r = sum(p,q);
While compiling the program at above line the compiler shows "/Function sum should have a prototype" error.

But I have defined the function sum above before calling it.

Comment: The function sum() is declared as a non-static member of class Complex. This means that you should call it on an existing object (for example p.sum(...). But in your case what you can probably do is declare it as static (class funciton) or outside the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your purpose the "sum" function should not be in the "Complex" class. Here a bit changed code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class Complex
{
public:

  int real;
  int imag;

  void getNo ()
  {
    cout << "Enter real part : " << endl;
    cin >> real;
    cout << "Enter imaginary part : " << endl;
    cin >> imag;
  }

  void showNo ()
  {
    cout << real << "+" << imag << "i";
  }


};

Complex sum (Complex c1, Complex c2);

int main ()
{
  //clrscr ();
  Complex p, q, r, s;
  p.getNo ();
  q.getNo ();
  cout << endl << "First complex number is : ";
  p.showNo ();

  cout << endl << "Second complex number is : ";
  q.showNo ();

  r = sum (p, q);
  cout << endl << "Addtion of the complex no is : ";
  r.showNo ();

  getch ();
}

Complex sum (Complex c1, Complex c2)
{
  Complex
    a;
  a.real = c1.real + c2.real;
  a.imag = c1.imag + c2.imag;
  return a;
}
```

**Edit**

Functions in class require an instance (object) of class.
Simply you **CAN** do this:

```
p.getNo();
t.sum();
myComplexNum.getReal();
```

But in your code you are trying to do this which you **CAN NOT**:

```
a = getNo();
b = sum();
getReal();
```

Additionally you **CAN** make the function **static** like other answer.
static functions and variables does not require an instance. Calling:

```
// We have 1 Box named b
Box b;
b.setHeight(5);
b.setWidth(3);
b.setDepth(3);

//ClassName::StaticVariable;
int c1 = Box::count;     // returns 1 

//ClassName::StaticFunction(Parameters);
int c2 = Box::getCount();        // returns 1
```

Comment: Please advise why it is causing error when I write the sum function in complex class.
If I am not wrong I can declare a function in class and then define it outside class using scope resolution(::) operator.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a function (a method) in a class, this method can be called on a instance of this class (a object).
In the given code the function Complex sum (Complex c1, Complex c2); should be called on an object of type Complex.

But as the function doesn't change anything inside the object, it rather creates a new object and returns it, you should better declare a static method.

```
static Complex sum(Complex, Complex);
```

in this case you can call the function without an existing Complex object.
The syntax is the following :

```
r = Complex::sum(a, b);
```